# Why I need to modify "etc\hosts" to be able to open the website?

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, iis, hosts

I have a web-server in my network which its IP is `192.168.249.10`. When I try to open it using its IP address in the browser, I face the following result:

http:

[image]

https:

[image]

As you see above, I can't open the homepage. But when I modify my `etc\hosts` to assign the domain name to its IP address, then I can open it:

hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.


192.168.249.10 xyz.abc.com
```

And I have:

[image]

*Note that I typed `xyz.abc.com` in the address bar only and then it automatically redirected to `https` and added `public/home/login`*.

Writing `https://192.168.249.10/public/home/login` still doesn't work!

The question is:

1. Why I need to assign the IP to this **specific** domain name in the host file? Does the `hosts` file do anything other than a local replacement(name with IP address)?
2. How they did this? (The web-server owner)

Answer (score 4):

1. No the `hosts` file does not do anything extra - it simply allows you to resolve the DNS query for `xyz.abc.com` right on your computer instead of sending it to the appropriate authoritative DNS server. The name or ip address you write into browser is sent the the web-server as well. Administrator of the web-server can view this information and disable access when you connect to IP address and not the hostname `xyz.abc.com`. This way you can run multiple websites on same ip address.
2. Depends on the web-server used. Each is configured different way. Generally you can use logic and even regular expressions to match ip addresses, domain names and resources in the request and then choose what do you provide to the client. To change this behavior you will need administrative access to the web-server.

Comment: The questioner can verify that the browser string is being checked by adding an extra entry for `xyz.abc.com`: if this is used I would expect error 404 again. If not, there may be an exclusion for numeric IP addresses in order to ignore web crawlers and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The web server is probably set up to identify virtual hosts by hostname. This means the browser must send the 'host' http header. In your case 'host: xyz.abc.com'. So the web server knows which site to deliver.
The browser does this if you use the name to connect, but of course can't when you don't supply a name, but the ip.